# CakePHP 3.x add different validation rules for frontend controller

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

I would like to create the custom validation function in cakephp 3.x
In CakePHP I've frontend and backend panels. Frontend have more fields comparing the backend panel. `public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)`. This validation function is call after the action call.

But I want to call a different validation function which will be specify in the controller and check the validation for other fields that are on frontend.

For Example, I have a field name 'company', but it is not in backend. I want to add require validation rule on server site for frontend.

Following function is created on the model:

```php
public function companyValidation(Validator $validator) {
    $validator
        ->requirePresence('company', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('company');
    return $validator;
}
```

How can I call to `companyValidation()` function in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, rename your function from `companyValidation` to `validationCompany`. Then, when you are patching your entity, use `$x = $this->Table->patchEntity($x, $this->request->data, ['validate' => 'company']);`

This is covered in the ["Validating data" section of the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html), particularly [Using and Different Validation Set](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-a-different-validation-set).